# Separate Identity Server with ABP Framework

Tags: angular, abp

#### Separate Identity Server Issues

- My **ABP Framework version** : 3.1.2
- My **User Interface** Angular
- My database provider EF Core

I created a module ABP Framework with separate Identity Server using ( ABP CLI )
, When i tried to connect with Identity Server, although I connected, I lost the all the information.

It can't local storage information.

[image]

[image]

Why !!

thank you

Comment: Follow this issue: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7485

Comment: My answer is here : https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7485#issuecomment-776685259